# Titanium DocumentViewer not showing document

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

My appcelerator alloy app has a section that displays a list of protocols used by employees in a listview(There are about 25), when a row is tapped, it should open the corresponding PDF document in the assets/protocol_pdf folder. In *iOS 11.2.1*, the document viewer opens, but the PDF is not displayed, only the filename followed by PDF document(see image). Everything works just fine in iOS 10 and prior.

I used the code example from http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2015/08/appcelerator-pdf-viewer-demo/ to open the PDF.

Additionally, using the exact code from the appcelerator documentation(http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.DocumentViewer) in a new test project results in the same problem.

At this point i'm not sure how to solve the issue. I can only guess that something in where the file is saved and how it is accessed is different. Any suggestions are appreciated.

My Code:

```
function onItemClick(e){    
    var item = $.listView.sections[e.sectionIndex].items[e.itemIndex];

    Ti.API.info('Opening ' + item.properties.file);
    if(OS_IOS){
        openResourcePDF(item.properties.file);
    } else{
        Alloy.Globals.Navigator.open("androidPDF", {file: item.properties.file});
    }
}

function openResourcePDF(fileName){
    var appFile;
    appFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, fileName);

    var appfilepath = appFile.nativePath;
    viewPDF(appfilepath);
}

function viewPDF(appfilepath){
    docViewer = Ti.UI.iOS.createDocumentViewer({url:appfilepath});
    docViewer.show();
}
```

Image showing how viewer brings it up:
[image]

Comment: Having the same issue and have filed a Jira ticket: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-5534

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just want to use that on iOS. Try this:

```
function openResourcePDF(fileName) {
    var appFile;
    appFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, fileName);

    var appfilepath = appFile.nativePath;
    viewFile(appfilepath);
}
```

Comment: This shows more than what I was using previously, it attempts to load the PDF vs just showing the file name, but it still results in the same after a brief loading icon. What I ended up doing was loading it up in a web view based on the test code in this appcelerator jira: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-25185